# CODEIGNITER how to join 3 tables to be used in multilogin user level

Tags: codeigniter

[here is my database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpuxK.png)
good day everyone i would like to ask how to join 3 tables in codeigniter. my aim is i want to join the tables for the login. i can login with the student but when i login with the instructor i cannot because i dont know how to join the three tables .

```
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_users');
        $this->db->join('tbl_student', 'tbl_student.student_id = tbl_users.user_id');
        $this->db->where('idnumber', $idnumber);  
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this way

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_users');
$this->db->join('tbl_student', 'tbl_student.student_id = tbl_users.user_id');
$this->db->join('tbl_instructor', 'tbl_instructor.instructor_id = tbl_users.user_id','left');
$this->db->where('tbl_users.user_id', $id); 
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: i had a error in the where tbl_users.user_id , $id

Comment: check the where clause as the requirement of your query, `tbl_users.user_id , $id` is supposed to get all the data from these three tables.